# Is there a general solution to make the UHD 3840 x 2160 notebook show bigger icons and fonts?

Tags: display, fonts, resolution

I got a UHD notebook before (Lenovo Yoga), and it had UHD 3840 x 2160 resolution.  One problem is the text and icons on the app's UI can be really small.  Is there a way to solve it so everything works?

(Example, the VLC player's play and pause buttons can be really small. And we can configure the font to be used for webpages, but if the webpages set a font size to override it, then it may still go to the smaller fonts and we have to keep magnify different webpages by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd>. I like Macbook Pro's Retina that for graphics or videos, it can be 4x resolution but for text and icons, it is automatically 2x width and height.)

Answer (score 2):

Display scaling. Right-click empty space on desktop, select *Display settings*. Scaling is the first setting in *Scale and layout* group.

Comment: so if you scale everything up, that defeats the purpose of UHD 3840 x 2160? You may as well just buy a 1080p display?

Comment: @nonopolarity No, it scales UI elements, not the whole display. Fonts and icons are scaled up to match the display, but you still have the entire resolution for graphics.

Comment: @nonopolarity Mokubai is right. Scaling is separate from resolution. It maintains configured resolution, but draws user interface elements scaled. Things will be larger, but no pixels will go to waste.

Comment: oh is this a new thing?  I remember when I got the notebook... (some 6, 7 years ago?) it probably didn't have that (or else the manufacturer might have automatically set it before they ship it).

Comment: @nonopolarity It's there since Windows XP, but was improved significantly in Windows 10.

Comment: @gronostaj it'd be weird when I got the Yoga and then Yoga 3, that both of them didn't have it set if that's the case.  I was working with tiny buttons... so either MS or Lenovo didn't the job right